# Search Document by name in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I've working on a c++ project involving alfresco. I want to search a document by name, but the webscripts provided by alfresco requires fileId. I don't want to create a custom new webscript.
so the question is there any existing webscript that supports search by name of the document?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Search in the Share UI? Explorer? From an external system? What format do you want your results in? HTML? JSON? XML? Other?

Comment: I'm writing a c++ code which searches the document in the alfresco from external system, the result format can either be in Json or xml

Comment: Have you thought about using CMIS? That'd let you query the repo, find things, traverse, fetch the contents etc

Comment: I used cmis i was able to query and fetch document based on the document id, My scenario is know the folder name and document name i want to get the details of that document based on the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a repository-tier webscript designed for search purpose: `http://host:port/alfresco/service/slingshot/node/search`, it accepts many url params but the important ones are : `q`, `lang` and `store`.
An example would be like this : `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/node/search?q=%40name%3A%22name%22&lang=lucene&store=workspace%3A%2F%2FSpacesStore`

where `q = @name:"name"`, `lang=lucene`
and `store=workspace://SpacesStore`

Webscript response will be in `json` format by default.

Answer (score 2):

The buildin Alfresco keyword search webscripts would at list allow you to search the repo for a given searchterm and to retrieve them for example as an atom feed.
Have a look at the webscript package located below 
`http://<yourAlfrescoHost>/alfresco/service/index/package/org/alfresco/repository/search`